# I am using Jsoup to perform some actions on a website But I am having troubles getting the url right

Tags: android, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I use [this](http://elearninghub.somee.com/Exam/AddExamType) website I already logged in with these credentials 
email:teacher@gmail.com
password:tttt
I got the cookies and saved it to my App ..but whenever I try to add new exam type  I got error fetching url exception I use Jsoup

here's the code

```
 private fun addExam() {
    Log.d(TAG, "addExam: -----------------------")
    try{
        val addExamResponse=Jsoup.connect(getString(R.string.addExamUrl))
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
             .cookies(Common.sessionCookies)
            .execute()

        val document=addExamResponse.parse()
        Log.d(TAG, "addExam: ------------------------------------------")
        val authToken:String=document.select("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").first().attr("value")
        Log.d(TAG, "addExam: ************************** ${addExamResponse.url()}")
        val formData: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        formData["utf8"] = "e2 9c 93"
        formData["ExamTypeName"]=examType.text.toString()
        formData["Description"]=examDesc.text.toString()
        formData["__RequestVerificationToken"] = authToken

        //Log.d(TAG, "addExam: ----------------------------${Common.sessionCookies}--------------------")

        val examListPage = Jsoup.connect(getString(R.string.addExamUrl))
            .data(formData)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .cookies(Common.sessionCookies)
            .execute()

        Log.d(TAG, "getData: --------------------------------${examListPage.url()}")

        if (examListPage.url().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains("teacher")){
            runOnUiThread {
                progressBar.hide()
            }
            startActivity(Intent(this,HomeActivity::class.java))

            finish()
        }
        else{

            runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Something went wrong!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e:IOException){
        Log.d(TAG, "addExam: -------------------------IO EXCEPTION---------------------${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Without try and catch the app crashes with this exception .Stack trace::

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.e_learninghub, PID: 10508
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=http://elearninghub.somee.com/Exam/AddExamType
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:682)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:629)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:261)
    at com.example.e_learninghub.NewExamActivity.addExam(NewExamActivity.kt:65)
    at com.example.e_learninghub.NewExamActivity.access$addExam(NewExamActivity.kt:19)
    at com.example.e_learninghub.NewExamActivity$addExamType$1.invokeSuspend(NewExamActivity.kt:35)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:235)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuation.run(Dispatched.kt:81)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.Task.run(Tasks.kt:94)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:586)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:732)
```

Comment: What exception is it? Include the stacktrace to make it more clear.

Comment: IO Exception I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 suggests there was something wrong on server side. Your code looks OK, so probably there was something wrong with your parameters. Are you sure `ExamTypeName` and `Description` are not empty?
Try displaying parameters before you send them:

```
Log.d(TAG, "formData: --------------------------------${formData}")
```